# Does PHP 5.x have some kind of HashSet or Set Class?

Tags: php, data-structures, spl

I'm used to Java where I have `HashSets`, `ArrayLists` and other `Collections`. But I'm workting on a PHP project right now.

I need to create a set, fill that set with objects (Strings in this case), but the Set can only contain each object once. In addition I want to remove a certain object in the end from this set if it exists. This would be pretty easy with the Java collection classes. But how can I implement that in PHP?

Are there any methods of `array()` that I am missing? I'm using PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 10):

If it's just strings, you can use arrays as sets:

```
$arr['str1'] = null;
$arr['str2'] = null;
$arr['str1'] = null;

print_r(array_keys($arr));
```

You only potential problem is that numeric strings are implicitly converted to integers, if possible. But that's usually not a problem in PHP because the type doesn't matter in most circumstances.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest to being right, but it still feels weired to implement a Set like Datastructure this way.

Comment: @PascalKlein Eh, I kinda like that there's one data structure that does it all. Fewer types to keep track of :)

Comment: @PascalKlein, this is only many many years later, but this is actually how the Java HashSet works. It does a bit more for checking if what you're adding is a duplicate, but the backing object is a HashMap.

Answer (score 6):

PHP documentation says:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that
>   associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several
>   different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash
>   table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack,
>   queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees
>   and multidimensional arrays are also possible.

So maybee(!) you don't need a HashSet, because a normal array is implemented already as a kind of an optimized index structure :)

Comment: The question was how to store only UNIQUE items, not if there is a basic data structure like one fits all array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure, but I think `SplObjectStorage` does what you want:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php

Oh, and strings are not objects. So you can just do this:

```
$foo['bar'] = true;
```

and the array will work as a way to uniquely store the strings.

Comment: SplObjectStorage can be used as set, but only if you are ok with using identity as equality. 5.4 adds a getHash method to SplObjectStorage, but from the code it seems it's not actually the hash code used for performance in Java, but actually equal hash means object equality as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array(1, 3, 6, 4, 3, 3, 7, 1);
$hashset = array();
foreach ($values as $value){
    if (!array_key_exists($value, $hashset)){
        echo $value." ";
        $hashset[$value] = true;
    }
}
```

Prints:
1 3 6 4 7

Comment: I agree that it would be great if PHP implemented a HashSet to provide same or similar functionality. My code can probably be made cleaner, or other tricks exists to simulate a HashSet, but it will still not give you the readability that a class named HashSet would provide.